# How to Include Metadata for Individual Fields in a multipart/form-data Response?

Tags: java, rest, multipartform-data, api-design

I have an API developed in Java 20 and Jakarta EE 10 with the Wildfly server. In this API, I can create multiple `BatchTechnicalRecordAttachments` at once. Each `BatchTechnicalRecordAttachment` is associated with both an `Attachment` and a `BatchTechnicalRecord`.

When receiving the data, I know that each file is associated with a `BatchTechnicalRecord` because the `key` corresponds to the `id` of the `BatchTechnicalRecord`. Then, on the server, I process and save the file for the respective `BatchTechnicalRecord`.

Here's an example of the data sent:
[image: Postman Example]

The problem is as follows: I want to return the data in the `multipart/form-data` format as well. However, based on the example above, if I send 3 attachments for `BatchTechnicalRecord` with ID 1 and 1 attachment for `BatchTechnicalRecord` with ID 2, how can I return the `BatchTechnicalRecordAttachment ID` that was created along with the existing `BatchTechnicalRecord ID`?

One of the solutions I explored was to return the `key` as a JSON object, which would contain both the `idBatchTechnicalRecord` and the `idBatchTechnicalRecordAttachment` (created on the server) like this:
[image: Postman Response Example]

However, I'm uncertain if this approach aligns with best practices for such scenarios.

Another solution I considered was to modify the endpoint to accept only one `BatchTechnicalRecord` request at a time. This would result in a URL structure like: `/api/batches/technical-records/{ID_BATCH_TECHNICAL_RECORD}/attachments`. This solution would require the consuming client to make separate requests for each record.

I'd appreciate insights and advice on whether these approaches are recommended or if there are alternative, more standard practices for handling this situation.